# Is there some way to set a global default value for the length of animations in SVG

Tags: animation, svg

I want to set a global value for the duration of animations in SVG, perhaps via CSS.  However the code below does not set the desired duration.

```
  <style>
     .animate {
      dur: 5s
     }
  </style>
  <animateTransform class="animate" id="at1" attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="showLine.begin+0s" fill="freeze" from="0,100" to="0,500"/>
```

Is there some way to set a global default value for the length of animations in SVG?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, SMIL animations use attributes rather than CSS properties so you can't set them using CSS.